# ng-click works if user clicks twice

Tags: html, angularjs, pug

I'm very new to AngularJS. Im making a project using jade and angular. I have this simple form, and when I click the button the function doesn't get called. The click listener works **only** if I do a double click. It **doesn't** work if I do a single click.

This only happens in Mozzila

Here is the code

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  title LoginForm
  link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="login.css")
  meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
  script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js")
  script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js")
  script(type="text/javascript", src="js/functions.js") 
  script.
    var app = angular.module('WebApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.login = function(){
        alert($scope.username+" & "+$scope.password);
      };
    });
  body(ng-app="WebApp")
    article.login-form(ng-controller="myCtrl")
      img.logo(src="assets/logo.png")
      form.login
        .input-box
          input(type="text", ng-model="username")
          label username
          img(src="assets/user.png")
        .input-box
          input(type="password", ng-model="password")
          label password
          img.pass(src="assets/pass.png")
        a.button.button-ink(href="#", ng-click="login()") Login
      a.forgot-pass(href="#") Forgot your password?
```

Comment: I tried your code on fiddlesalad.com and it works right away with a single click, are you sure the problem isn't in your environment/computer?

Comment: Can you debug it and see what happen at the first click?

Comment: Please create a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out why it was doing this. I had a separate script for  a ripple effect that was messing with it.